# Excel dynamic range cell

Tags: arrays, excel

I need to dynamically select cell with same text value.
For example, as shows below, a formula that can select in TableName value from TABLE_A for range TABLE_A and ColumnName, and then change dynamically selection for all the value of table_B.

```
TableName   ColumnName
TABLE_A     colname1
TABLE_A     colname2
TABLE_A     colname3
TABLE_A     colname4
TABLE_B     colname1
TABLE_B     colname2
TABLE_B     colname3
TABLE_B     colname4
```

Anyone can suggest me some advice ?

I tried to select value but I have difficult to find last right row of the range.

Comment: Try harder, maybe Google Translate i.e. the words are English but the meaning isn't.